# Как из текста сделать по типу ТекСТ на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.5

Примерный текст: У лукоморья дуб зелёный.

Надо чтобы из примерного текста получилось по типу:
у ЛуКомоРья дУб зЕлёнЫй

у лУкОморЬя дуБ ЗелЁнЫй

у ЛукОморЬЯ дуБ ЗЕлЁнЫй

Каждый раз по разному и все варианты.

Либо чтобы готовый текст выводился в консоле либо в txt документе.

Заранее Спасибо.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример своего варианта решения, за вас задачу никто решать не будет, сообщество помогает, а не выполняет работу

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: text = 'У лукоморья дуб зеленый'
txt = text.upper()
print(txt)
Я думал что-то по типу этого, но я не знаю тогда как разделить и уменьшить текст.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

string = 'У лукоморья дуб зелёный'
out_string = ''.join(random.choice((str.upper, str.lower)) (x) for x in string)
print(out_string)

У ЛУКоМоРЬЯ ДУб ЗеЛЁНыЙ
```

Comment: Можно ли сделать не через random.choice

А примерно:

for x in range(len(string)):

    a = ''.join(((str.upper, str.lower)) (x) for x in string)

    print(a)

Comment: С помощью random.shuffle() просто не могу понять что бы они не повторялись.

Comment: @Опача shuffle просто перемешает всю последовательность в случайном порядке, т.е. вы на выходе получаете неудобоваримый текст типа "ыёрзоУмнйдл яок л еуубь"